# unable to populate a select dropdown list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using websql to store some data for a web app. Now I am trying to retrieve it and populate it into a select dropdown box. I used the html function to set the values. But for some reason, the select dropdown box does not get populated.

HTML file

[HTML File](http://pastebin.com/jugnk4w4)

Here is the Javascript file

```
var dbConnection=null;
var dbName='ExpensesAppDb';
var dbVersion='1.0';
var dbDisplayName='Expenses Application Database';
var dbSize=1024*1024*5;
var categoryTable="categories";
var name="name";
var _id="id";
var categoryTableQuery="create table "+categoryTable+"("+_id+" integer primary key,"
+ name +" text)";
var options="";

$(function()
{
dbConnection=openDatabase(dbName,dbVersion,dbDisplayName,dbSize);
createCategoryTable();
init();
fetchCategories();
});

createCategoryTable=function()
{
dbConnection.transaction(function(tx){
 tx.executeSql(categoryTableQuery,[],
 function(){alert('Category Table created');},
 function(tx,error){ alert(error.message);});
});
};

insertCategory=function(aName)
{
dbConnection.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("insert into "+categoryTable+"("+name
    +") values(?)",[aName],
    function(tx,result)
    {

    },
    function()
    {

    }
)
    });
        };


fetchCategories=function()
{
dbConnection.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("SELECT "+_id+","+name +" FROM "+categoryTable, [],
    function(SQLTransaction, data){
    for (var i = 0; i "+aName+""
}

function populateCategoryList()
{
 $('#expensesCategory').html(options);
 $("#expensesName").val("Hello");
}

function init()
{
    insertCategory("Food");
    insertCategory("Rent");
    insertCategory("Gas");
    insertCategory("Entertainment");
}
```

PS: How does one show the source of the HTML File over here. I guess the engine was parsing the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to refresh the display state of the selection box by using
$("#expensesCategory").selectmenu('refresh', true);